# Pairing Row Values in Any Order

Tags: unique-constraint

I'm trying to find % of unique pairs that exist in two columns. For example

[image]

Where 1,6 and 6,1 / 2,3 and 3,2 are unique pairs. So the % of matched pairs is 33%

Comment: Please tag you database, version included

Answer (score 3):

Doesn't make much sense:

- the number of pairs is **6**, -- not relevant to the question...
- the number of unique permuted pairs is **4** - far more relevant...
- There are 2 matched pairs so I make the number of unique to matched pairs at **4/2**, i.e. **50%**...

Notwithstanding the objection above, what you can do is something like this, using the [LEAST](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-GREATEST-LEAST) and [GREATEST](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-GREATEST-LEAST) (almost standard - see discussion below) SQL functions.

This example (see [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=871e394f60fae30a45d67147878bced2)) is from PostgreSQL, however see discussion at the end.

```
CREATE TABLE test (col1 INTEGER, col2 INTEGER);
```

populate with your data:

```
INSERT INTO test VALUES (1, 6), (2,3), (3, 2), (4, 7), (5, 8), (6, 1);
```

First query:

```
SELECT LEAST(col1, col2) AS mn_c, GREATEST(col1, col2) AS mx_c,
COUNT(*) 
FROM test
GROUP BY 1, 2
```

Result:

```
mn_c    mx_c    count
   2       3        2
   4       7        1
   1       6        2
   5       8        1
```

Then:

```
SELECT COUNT(cnt1) AS matched_count,
       ROUND(COUNT(cnt1)/(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM test)::FLOAT * 100) AS percentage
FROM 
(
  SELECT LEAST(col1, col2) AS mn_c, GREATEST(col1, col2) AS mx_c,
  COUNT(*) AS cnt1 
  FROM test
  GROUP BY 1, 2
  HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
) AS t
```

Result:

```
matched_count   percentage
            2           33
```

A version of the above code should work for most servers - see [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/187090/does-sql-server-support-greatest-and-least-if-not-what-is-the-common-workaround) for a discussion of the LEAST and GREATEST functions in other servers - works pretty much for all of them except MS SQL Server.

p.s. have you considered what happens if you have duplicate columns as follows?

```
INSERT INTO test VALUES (1, 6), (2,3), (3, 2), (4, 7), (5, 8), (6, 1), (5,5), (5,5)
```

Note the duplication of a duplication - `(5,5)` - see [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=dd9b7b2357f727a1080012e3700d5aca) for the differences which emerge between my approach and that of @McNets. My solution says that there are 3/8 matched pairs, but McNets says different. Not sure if I completely understand what his SQL is doing?

Anyway, interesting question (+1) - why do you want to do this? p.s. welcome to the forum! :-)

Answer (score 2):

Using standard SQL could be:

```
SELECT
  COUNT(*) * 100 / (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM t)
FROM
    t t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM   t t2
                  WHERE  t2.col1 = t1.col2
                  AND    t2.col2 = t1.col1);
```

> ```
> | Percent |
> | ------: |
> |      33 |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=56d52af0d6bcc07df7c54cd35b2222e5)*

Comment: Would you care to have a look [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=dd9b7b2357f727a1080012e3700d5aca) and comment on the differences between your answer and mine for a duplication of a duplication - i.e. `(5,5)`?

Comment: Hi @ Verace, I think OP should clarify whether duplicate pairs should be considered once or not.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to do as follows (if your DB is MS SQL)

```
Create table #Pairs
(c1 int,
 c2 int
);
go

insert into #Pairs
values 
(1,6),
(2,3),
(3,2),
(4,7),
(5,8),
(6,1)
go

select p1.c1, p1.c2, 
        p2.PairCount,
        --(select count (*) from PairTest) as TotalPairs,
        (p2.PairCount + 0.0) / (select count (*) from PairTest) as Pair_Percent
from #Pairs as p1
    join 
        (
        select (c1+ c2) as Pair, COUNT (*) PairCount
        from #Pairs
        group by (c1+ c2)
        ) as p2 on (p1.c1 + p1.c2) = p2.pair
go

Drop table #Pairs;
```